# (IntelliJ GUI Designer) Runtime NullPointerException upon adding a component to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Working on an IntelliJ plugin and trying to add a `JLabel` component to a `JPanel` on click on a `JButton` and this is a snippet of my code.

```
addLabelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Hi, JLabel!"));
        contentPane.revalidate();
        contentPane.repaint();
    }
});
```

On click on the `JButton` I'm getting a run time error.

> 2020-01-02 17:44:16,118 [  30502]  ERROR -
>   llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null  java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager.addLayoutComponent(GridLayoutManager.java:134)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1152)     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:436)

Comment: Which version of intellij and which java version ? Also before running the java you can add --illegal-access=deny so that java will throw exception on illegal reflective access and you can check the trace to identify the cause.

Comment: @Balaji I have updated the question and added the IntelliJ and Java versions can you take a look again?

Comment: Don't post images of text. [Edit] to add the text itself!

Comment: @YamanKATBY can you share the updated trace by running your program with --illegal-access=deny

Comment: *trying to add a JLabel to a JPanel* - your code is actually adding a `Label`, which is an AWT component, not a Swing component.

Comment: @camickr I have changed the Label to JLabel and still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a ton of researching, I've got the point. the problem is you can't add a component to a `JPanel` if the *Layout Manager* of the `JPanel` is equal to *GridLayoutManager (IntelliJ)*.

If you have the same problem:

- Go to the *GUI Designer*
- Select the `JPanel` that you want to add a component to it
- From the properties panel, change the *Layout Manager* to anything but *GridLayoutManager (IntelliJ)* or *FormLayout (JGoodies)*

IntelliJ GUI Designer properties panel
[image: IntelliJ GUI Designer properties panel]

Or programmatically

```
contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add components to a GridLayoutManager but first you need to set the layout to [specify the rows, cols, hgap, and vgap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

```
myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3, 4, 4));

myPanel.add(button);
```